# Special keys in Eclipse Issue - IDE always asks for confirmation

Tags: eclipse, key, copy-paste, confirmation

Last days I have an issue with eclipse when I press special keys inside the eclipse
IDE.

e.g when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
then a small window appears on the bottom right corner of the IDE which
is like this:

Copy | <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

The same is for other keys.. I got:
Inline Editing|Enter (when press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
Paste|<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>         (when <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>)

It is really slowing down typing because it gets the focus and need confirmation clicking
on the right part of the small window.

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The pop-ups you are seeing are the "keybinding conflict" popups. These are common when you have two different plugins defining the same keybinding and looks [like these](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rmc/v7r5m0/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/keys3.png). This may happen if you installed some plugin which attempts to override the default bindings.

You may investigate your current bindings using "Window>Preferences>General>Keys". Enter the binding (eg. "Ctrl+C") in the filter field (it has "type filter text") and see all the commands that have this key combination bind to. If you have two different commands with same "When" parameter, then there's a conflict.

You may "unbind command" and then bind it again. Or try using "Restore command" button.

Also you may try to un-install the ill-behaving plugin, if you don't need it actually.